# Combining 2 pandas created pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Pivot Table A

```
                                      Balance  Deployed
Type      Environment OS     Model                     
SupplierA Network 1   Win 10 Model 1      1.0       4.0
                             Model 2      2.0       5.0
          Network 2   Win 10 Model 1      3.0       6.0
                      Win 7  Model 2      NaN       7.0
```

Pivot Table B

```
                                      Balance  Deployed
Type      Environment OS     Model                     
SupplierA Network 3   Win 10 Model 1      NaN       8.0
                             Model 2      NaN       9.0
          Network 4   Win 10 Model 1      NaN      10.0
                      Win 7  Model 2      NaN      11.0
                      Win 7  Model 3      NaN      12.0
```

Result

```
                                       N3/4 Bal       Bal    N3/4 Deployed    Deployed
Type      Environment OS     Model                     
SupplierA Network 1   Win 10 Model 1        Nan       1.0            8.0         4.0
                             Model 2        Nan       2.0            9.0         5.0
          Network 2   Win 10 Model 1        Nan       3.0           10.0         6.0
                      Win 7  Model 2        Nan       NaN           11.0         7.0
                      Win 7  Model 3        Nan       NaN           12.0         7.0
```

Network 3 and Network 4 is actually the subset of Network 1 and Network 2 respectively.

How do I combine the pivot table B result into Pivot table A result using python pandas.

Sample code:

```
filter1 = df[(df["Type"]!="")]
table1 = pd.pivot_table(filter1,index=                
["Type","Env","OperSys","Model"],columns=
["AssetLifecycleStatus"],values="Serial         
Number",aggfunc='count',margins=True,dropna=True)
table1 = table1.reindex(['Network 1','Network 2'], level=1)
table1 = table1.reindex_axis(['Balance','Deployed], axis=1)
table1.index = table1.index.set_names('Environment', level=1)
table1.index = table1.index.set_names('OS', level=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since pivot tables share the same multindex, consider using [`.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
mergedf = table1.join(table2, lsuffix='_', rsuffix='')
```

To demonstrate with random data (seeded to reproduce same values):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time

LETTERS = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
epoch_time = int(time.time())

dfs = []
for i in range(2):
    np.random.seed(1000 + i)
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [np.random.randint(1,3) for _ in range(50)],
                        'GROUP': ["".join(np.random.choice(LETTERS[1:5],1)) for _ in range(50)],                   
                        'NUM': np.random.randn(50)*100,
                        'BOOL': [np.random.choice([True,False],1).item(0) for _ in range(50)],
                        'DATE': [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(np.random.randint(1407165459,epoch_time)) for _ in range(50)]})

    tmp['YEAR'] = tmp['DATE'].dt.year

    dfs.append(tmp.pivot_table(index=['GROUP', 'BOOL', 'ID'], 
               columns='YEAR', values='NUM', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0))

mdf = dfs[0].join(dfs[1], lsuffix='_', rsuffix='')
```

**Outputs**

```
print(dfs[0])
YEAR                  2014        2015        2016        2017
GROUP BOOL  ID                                                
B     False 1     0.000000 -109.692126  -87.286656    0.000000
            2     0.000000  -36.775578    0.000000    0.000000
      True  1    85.743275    0.000000   41.534745   80.202451
            2     0.000000    0.000000   65.034285    0.000000
C     False 1     0.000000  -93.696928  139.442275   24.999852
            2     0.000000   86.726082    0.000000    0.000000
      True  1    29.132019   64.424261    0.000000  108.224081
            2   145.431373 -111.116278    0.000000 -185.134785
D     False 1     0.000000  113.341723    0.000000    0.000000
            2     0.000000   98.740384  137.415560    0.000000
      True  1     0.000000  -63.477170  164.748952    0.000000
            2     0.000000 -457.161979    0.000000   -8.200619
E     False 1   146.204730  104.853072  196.485406 -143.713939
            2   269.964586    0.000000 -379.256574    0.000000
      True  1  -142.337059  -15.032559 -153.805456   17.793711
            2   -74.200575    0.000000    0.000000  -17.805445

print(dfs[1])
YEAR                  2014        2015        2016        2017
GROUP BOOL  ID                                                
B     False 1     0.000000  141.036715    7.471521    0.000000
            2     0.000000  150.056514  -95.408040   50.899685
      True  1    68.030610   52.015261   31.100536 -228.762932
            2     0.000000   51.645003    0.000000    1.253947
C     False 1     8.943704    0.000000    0.000000   96.047025
            2     0.000000  207.756386    0.000000   94.866648
      True  1     0.000000   10.923869  -24.716529    0.000000
            2     0.000000    0.000000  -36.847404    9.879019
D     False 1     8.454257   91.386381  -89.693662   33.769267
            2     0.000000   72.420881  130.951512   85.189272
      True  1   116.647215  -73.226222  -65.496555    0.000000
            2     0.000000  155.958910   47.444020  -29.872307
E     False 1     0.000000    0.000000 -111.854429 -159.037171
            2     0.000000    0.000000    2.417443  -75.488531
      True  1   -86.983855    0.000000  102.603068  -51.821700
            2     0.000000  -65.017149    0.000000    7.690244

print(mdf)
YEAR                 2014_       2015_       2016_       2017_        2014        2015        2016        2017
GROUP BOOL  ID                                                                                                
B     False 1     0.000000 -109.692126  -87.286656    0.000000    0.000000  141.036715    7.471521    0.000000
            2     0.000000  -36.775578    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  150.056514  -95.408040   50.899685
      True  1    85.743275    0.000000   41.534745   80.202451   68.030610   52.015261   31.100536 -228.762932
            2     0.000000    0.000000   65.034285    0.000000    0.000000   51.645003    0.000000    1.253947
C     False 1     0.000000  -93.696928  139.442275   24.999852    8.943704    0.000000    0.000000   96.047025
            2     0.000000   86.726082    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000  207.756386    0.000000   94.866648
      True  1    29.132019   64.424261    0.000000  108.224081    0.000000   10.923869  -24.716529    0.000000
            2   145.431373 -111.116278    0.000000 -185.134785    0.000000    0.000000  -36.847404    9.879019
D     False 1     0.000000  113.341723    0.000000    0.000000    8.454257   91.386381  -89.693662   33.769267
            2     0.000000   98.740384  137.415560    0.000000    0.000000   72.420881  130.951512   85.189272
      True  1     0.000000  -63.477170  164.748952    0.000000  116.647215  -73.226222  -65.496555    0.000000
            2     0.000000 -457.161979    0.000000   -8.200619    0.000000  155.958910   47.444020  -29.872307
E     False 1   146.204730  104.853072  196.485406 -143.713939    0.000000    0.000000 -111.854429 -159.037171
            2   269.964586    0.000000 -379.256574    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    2.417443  -75.488531
      True  1  -142.337059  -15.032559 -153.805456   17.793711  -86.983855    0.000000  102.603068  -51.821700
            2   -74.200575    0.000000    0.000000  -17.805445    0.000000  -65.017149    0.000000    7.690244
```